# rails 3 sass compiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass

Hello I have one question I have my file main.scss which is in public/stylesheets/scss. In documentation is written:

> By default, .sass and .scss files are
>   placed in public/stylesheets/sass
>   (this can be customized with the
>   :template_location option). Then,
>   whenever necessary, they’re compiled
>   into corresponding CSS files in
>   public/stylesheets. For instance,
>   public/stylesheets/sass/main.scss
>   would be compiled to
>   public/stylesheets/main.css.

I have in my gemfile gem 'haml'
And from my view I do sth like this

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'main'
```

And the file is not found when I check the source(there is a file with with information about routing error). I guess that compiling it by hand it is not way to go so how I can make compile scss file to public/stylesheets automatic? What mean in documentation that they are compiled when necessary?
Thanks in advance

Comment: just to make sure you are running `sass --watch style.scss:style.css` while making changes to your stylesheet

Answer (score 4):

Put your .sass or .scss files in public/stylesheets/sass, not public/stylesheets/scss.  Then the stylesheets should automatically generate whenever you change the corresponding sass/scss file.  The generated stylesheets end up in public/stylesheets/.

Renaming the folder should make it all work.

EDIT: it looks like Rails 3.1 is going to be not only including SASS by default, but it will also be moving most of the stuff found in the public folder to the app folder... so this answer will only apply to versions of rails before 3.1.